# Get last inserted value and if statement mssql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have this database setup: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3076a/4

EDIT:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Sensor1](
    [SensorTime] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [SensorValue] [float] NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [SensorTime] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

INSERT INTO dbo.Sensor1(SensorTime, SensorValue) VALUES ('2014-03-17 11:10:34.343', 10);
INSERT INTO dbo.Sensor1(SensorTime, SensorValue) VALUES ('2014-03-17 11:20:34.343', 20);
INSERT INTO dbo.Sensor1(SensorTime, SensorValue) VALUES ('2014-03-17 11:30:34.343', 30);

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SelectLatestByDate]
    @name nvarchar(128),
    @date datetime
AS
    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)
    SET @sql = N'
        SELECT TOP 1 * FROM '+ QUOTENAME(@name) +' WHERE SensorTime <= @date ORDER BY SensorTime DESC
    '

    EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@date datetime', @date = @date
RETURN
```

Now, whenever a new value will be inserted, I want to make a check to see if it's not equal to the last value. If it's the same, it should not insert the value. Right now I have this stored procedure to do this, but it's slow and I'm wondering if there is a faster way...

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[PutData]
    @name nvarchar(128),
    @date datetime,
    @value float
AS
    DECLARE @Table TABLE
    (
        SensorTime datetime,
        SensorValue float
    )

    INSERT INTO @Table
    EXEC dbo.SelectLatestByDate @name, @date

    DECLARE @lastValue float
    SELECT @lastValue = [@Table].[SensorValue] FROM @Table

    IF (@lastValue != @value)
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)
        SET @sql = N'
            INSERT INTO ' + QUOTENAME(@name) + ' (SensorTime, SensorValue) VALUES (@date, @value)
        '

        EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@date datetime, @value float', @date = @date, @value = @value
    END
RETURN 0
```

The tablename should be variable, that's the reason I made a stored procedure for it

Comment: Can you show the definition of `dbo.SelectLatestByDate` ?

Comment: Added it in the topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you can use `NOT EXIST` condition with your `INSERT` statement to test for the existence of rows.

```
IF NOT EXISTS ( [subquery] ) INSERT INTO ... VALUES(...)
```

The document of `NOT EXIST` is here :
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188336.aspx

To specify the row which has the the maximum `SensorTime`, you can use `MAX( )` function like below:

```
MAX(SensorTime) = SensorTime
```

This means the maxmum value is equal to the value of this row.

The document of `MAX( )` function is here:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187751.aspx

So, Your code could go something like this:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT *  FROM Sensor1 WHERE SensorTime <= @date 
  AND SensorTime = MAX(SensorTime) AND SensorValue = @value
) 
INSERT INTO Sensor1 (SensorTime, SensorValue) VALUES (@date, @value)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, it works but the performance doesn't seem to increase a lot. I'm inserting data every ~10ms, and I still have duplicate values sometimes

Comment: Thank you. It is sometime useful to rebuild/refresh your indexes on your columns. In this case, to rebuild an Index of SensorTime could improve the performance, I guess. The document is here:http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187874(v=sql.105).aspx